# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown Navbar change caret with Plus and Minus Fontawesome 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am trying to find a solution now for days, but just don't get it. I have created a responsive Navbar with Dropdowns with Bootstrap 4. I would now like to replace the caret with a Plus and Minus at the end of the row to show on small devices and I would like to achieve that entirely with CSS.

So I have created the below HTML for the Navbar Dropdown.

```
 <!-- Navbar Top -->         
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom navbar-light">
 <div class="container justify-content-between">    

    <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button Menu -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler  mr-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbarMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbarMenu">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <!-- Link -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> 
    </li>

    <!-- Dropdown About Us-->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fab fa-jenkins d-lg-none d-xl-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> About  
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('about') }}"> About Us</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('our-club') }}">Our Club</a>                               
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('meetings') }}">Meetings</a>
      </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

My CSS

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
     display:block;
  }
 }  

 [data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f067";
 }  

 [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover:after {
    content: "\f068";
 }
```

The Problem I have got now is that I get shown a Plus and when I hover or click on it it shows a minus but when I click on it again to close the collapsed dropdown then it stays as a minus till I go on another dropdown. The second Problem is that I still get the caret shown as well, so it does not replace it. Is there a way to achieve it just with CSS?

I can remove the caret if I add the below CSS, but this will also remove my Plus sign.

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Font Awesome 5 JS+SVG version? If so, have you read [this](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements#with-svg-js)?

Comment: To be honest, this is a good question, but I would think no. I use Laravel 5.7 and added "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.3" into my package.json I then I added @import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
to my app.scss and after that run npm run watch. After that it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for this:

```css
[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f067";
}

.show [data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
  content: "\f068";
}
.dropdown-toggle {
  display: flex;
}
.dropdown-toggle:after {
  border: none;
}
```

In short, Bootstrap's caret is made of `border`, not `content`, and your `content` should be dependent on the dropdown's state (open - a.k.a. `.show`) rather than on `:hover`.

```css
.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f067";
}

.show > .dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
  content: "\f068";
}
.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  display: flex;
}
.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]:after {
  border: none;
}

/* 
 * I inflated [data-toggle]'s specificity by adding .dropdown-toggle to it as for 
 * some reason SO is loading bootstrap.min.css after the custom CSS
 * but you can use the CSS I posted in the answer if it's loaded after bootstrap.css
 * see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wy46msvh/
 */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Navbar Top -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom navbar-light">
  <div class="container justify-content-between">

    <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button Menu -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler  mr-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbarMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Navbar links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbarMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <!-- Link -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>

        <!-- Dropdown About Us-->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="fab fa-jenkins d-lg-none d-xl-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> About  
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. The caret is gone, but when I click on the Burger Icon than both Dropdowns (I have just added another dropdown) show the Minus, so before I even click on the "About" the Plus turns into a Minus and it turns on both of them. Any idea?

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working. It might have been a caching issue and I have rebuild it and now it is working!! Fantastic, Thank you very very much. I could just not figure it out and now it's finally working.

Comment: This is interesting. Curious if it's possible to have `About` be a link and independent from the Plus icon. So, plus will expand, but About will link. Can that be done?